# How to compare a localdate against list of localdates

Tags: java

If i have a list of localdates, and I need to compare a localdate against that list, and return the last date that is before that date, what would be the best approach.

For example, given the list:

01/01/2019
01/01/2020
01/01/2021
01/01/2022

if I feed it the date 30/12/2021, then I want the answer to return 01/01/2021

I was thinking i would just iterate the list until I found the first date which my given date is not before, then just return the previous entry in the list(unless that is the first entry, in which case i would return nothing)

The dates list has already been sorted in ascending order:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dates.size{}; i++)
{
  if (myDate.before(dates[i]) {
    if (i==0) {
      return null;
    }
    else {
      return dates[i-1];
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: Implementation you thought about would work only if the list of dates is chronologically sorted, and even then just returning the previous element could not work because previous element could be date equal to the given date and not before it. Think again and try to post some code.

Comment: See edited answer.  Thanks

Comment: see my answer and let me know if that's what you wanted.

Comment: Spot on that, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create list with some random dates
        List<LocalDate> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(LocalDate.of(2019, 3, 12));
        list.add(LocalDate.of(2019, 4, 11));
        list.add(LocalDate.of(2019, 8, 10));
        list.add(LocalDate.of(2019, 6, 9));

        System.out.println(getMostRecentBeforeDate(LocalDate.now(), list));
    }

    // this is our comparing/filtering method 
    private static LocalDate getMostRecentBeforeDate(LocalDate targetDate, List<LocalDate> dateList) {
        // we filter the list so that only dates which are "older" than our targeted date remain
        // then we get the most recent date by using compareTo method from LocalDate class and we return that date
        return dateList.stream().filter(date -> date.isBefore(targetDate)).max(LocalDate::compareTo).get();
    }
}
```

If you run the code above, you should get `2019-08-10` as the output, since that's the most recent date before current date (`LocalDate.now()`).